# Можно ли изменить конфигурацию persistence.xml после сборки?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли каким либо образом изменить persistence.xml после сборки проекта или же вынести его за пределы сборки?
Это нужно потому, что приложение нужно раскидать в разные места, и там будут разные данные для доступа к бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под "разными местами" имеются ввиду разные сервера приложений, то можно вынести настройки доступа к БД на сервер приложений.

Для этого нужно прописать в persistence.xml элемент jta-data-source. Например, для WildFly:

```
<persistence-unit name="my-persistence-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/MyDB</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

В нем можно прописать название источника данных (пула соединений к БД), который будет настраиваться по-разному на каждом сервере приложений.

Если же все-таки нужно изменять параметры в persistence.xml, то можно загружать их самостоятельно через [Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-):

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager", Maps.create(
        "javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser,
        "javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPass,
        "javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbUrl
));
```

Похожий вопрос на английском: [Change content in persistence.xml dynamically during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140082/change-content-in-persistence-xml-dynamically-during-execution)

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Второй вариант то что нужно для меня.